# Dropzonejs mulitple zones with file preview

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

Hoping that someone will be able to tell me where Im going wrong here .

Im using Dropzonejs to allow people to drop files for storage online, I have 8 zones on one page, each used for a different category, when someone drops a file they are saved with additional data depending on which zone they were dropped in for later retrieval .. this all works fine.

I then wanted each zone to show the thumbnails for each of the files on the server under its category on page refresh, this is where I get problems, using the follwing code I get all my files being shown in the bottom zone, and the others are empty. Its obviously a problem with the code that fetches current files and makes the thumbnails, but Im lost as to why.

If I only have one instance on a page it all works fine.

Heres the code I use to setup and instantiate each dropzone instance.

```
Dropzone.options.dzdiag = {
    url: "upload.php",
    previewsContainer: "#dzdiag",
    init: function() {
        thisDropzone = this;
        filetype = "diagnostic";
        var propid = <?php echo $id; ?>; // set value to current property id
        $.get('upload.php?propid='+propid+'&filetype='+filetype, function(data) { // get exisitng files and thumbnail
            $.each(data, function(key,value){
                var mockFile = { name: value.name, size: value.size, fileid: value.fileid,  };
                thisDropzone.options.addedfile.call(thisDropzone, mockFile);
                var pattern = /\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|tiff|png)$/i;
                if( pattern.test(value.name)){
                    thisDropzone.options.thumbnail.call(thisDropzone, mockFile, "uploads/"+value.name);
                }
            });
        });             

        thisDropzone.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData) {
            formData.append("propid", propid);
            formData.append("filetype", filetype);
        });

        thisDropzone.on("success", function(file, serverack) { 
            file.fileid = serverack;
        });

        thisDropzone.on("removedfile", function(file) {
            var delid = file.fileid;  
            $.post('upload.php?delid='+delid);
        }); 

    }
};
$("#dzdiag").dropzone();
```

Comment: found the answer .. but cant post it because of the 8 hour rule imposed on this forum to new users !!

Answer (score 0):

Simply changing the previewsContainer (on not specifying it) for each zone should get you what you want.